# How to execute callback only on the parent element, even though event was triggered by its child?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am working on a chat app. Each chat element has children of its own. And all the chats are inside of a `chatContainer`.

Now, if I add the event listener to the `chatContainer`, how do I execute the callback only on the parent element (chat) even though the event was triggered by one of its children (`chatChild`)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. In order to help, we need to see code that you're having trouble with. When we can see where you're having issues specifically we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the parent from the target (the element the event has been triggered on).

Let's imagine your chat elements have a `chat` class. The code should look like that

```js
chatContainer.addEventListener('the_event_of_your_choise', event => {
    chat = event.target.closest('.chat');
    // …

});
```